# Query usando LINQ e Generics C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, query, linq, genéricos

Estou com dificuldades para realizar uma consulta com LINQ usando Generics.

Algo como:

```
from x in session.Query<T>() " ??? "
```

Meu método recebe duas strings como parâmetros, nomeColuna e valorBusca.

```
public virtual object PesquisePorColunaValor(string colunaDeBusca, string valorDeBusca)
    {
         // TODO Query em LINQ
    }
```

Comment: Você quer fazer uma busca dinâmica de acordo com o valor passado por parâmetro certo?

Comment: ??? Diga qual é sua dúvida. Explique o que está acontecendo, onde você quer chegar, dê uma contexto ao que está fazendo. Aí tem um monte de coisa jogada sem sentido algum.

Comment: @Pedro Explique melhor a sua dúvida, acredito que o que voce quer é criar um metodo que execute uma query dinâmica para ser pesquisada em um Collections, se for isso, acho meio difícil de fazer isso utilizando o nome da coluna como String.

Comment: Isso Jéferson, é um método que serve para todas as entidades.
A busca é de acordo com o nome da coluna e do valor enviados por string.

Comment: from x in session.Query<T>() select x retorna todos os registros de T

Comment: @JulioBorges O problema é que não posso fugir desse padrão do método. Pois já tem muita coisa funcionando com ele.

Comment: Vou implementar sem o uso de generics por enquanto. Agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que você não consiga fazer esta busca dinâmica utilizando uma String para obter a coluna que vai ser pesquisada.

O ideal será utilizar os recursos [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/Bb549151%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) e [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Pesquisar(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    IQueryable<T> lquerySentenca = session.Query<T>().Where(predicate);
    return lquerySentenca;
}

public virtual List<T> PesquisarComList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Pesquisar(predicate).ToList();
}

public void Executando()
{
    List<Aluno> lst = Pesquisar<Aluno>(o => o.Nome == "Jose").ToList();
    List<Aluno> lst2 = PesquisarComList<Aluno>(o => o.Nome == "Jose").ToList();
}
```

Comment: Ok, farei um teste com essa implementação e darei retorno.